# JSF 2.0 p:tabView and ui:composite are not rendering html response completely

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I am Using 
WebSphere Application Server 7.0.0.25,
Myfaces 2.0.7,
Primefaces 3.4.1

I have the following page which is using p:tabView has 3 tabs

dashboard.xhtml
Dashboard is main page which has header.xhtml. and first tab has 4 radio buttons. on clicking of each radio button would load different code piece written in ***ui:composite*** using AJAX.
Second tabs has some buttons in footer of the p:dataTable. When I click on the button a dialog will show up the selected row in the datatable.

I see the following error in server logs.

> Error Rendering View[/dashboard.xhtml]
>                                    javax.faces.FacesException: Cannot find component with identifier ":tabView:panelGridNewUserDialog" referenced from "tabView:userList:addUserButton".

But when I see "View Source" in browser, HTML code is incomplete. I have put the p:dialog tags bottom of the AppUserManagement.xhtml. All that code is not rendered as HTML. And commandButton is not showing in dataTable footer

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<c:set var="webCtxRoot" value="#{request.contextPath}" />
<f:view locale="#{language.locale}">
    <h:head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
            href="#{webCtxRoot}/theme/ldapmanager.css" />
        <title>Welcome To Ldap Manager Application</title>
        <h:outputScript name="jsf.js" library="javax.faces" id="script_id" />
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form id="headerForm" prependId="false">
            <h:inputHidden value="#{authenticatedBackingBean.session}"
                id="sessionValidator" />
            <ui:include src="header.xhtml" />

            <p:spacer height="8" width="160" />
            <p:tabView id="tabView" dynamic="true" cache="true">
                <p:tab id="applicationUserManagementTab"
                    title="Application User Mgmt">
                    <ui:include src="AppUserManagement.xhtml" />
                </p:tab>
                <p:tab id="userManagementTab" title="User Management">
                    <p:panelGrid id="dashboardContentGrid" styleClass="panelDiv">
                        <p:row>
                            <p:column>
                                <p:panelGrid>
                                    <p:row>
                                        <p:column>
                                            <p:fieldset legend="Choose User Operation" id="buttonPanel">
                                                <p:selectOneRadio id="userOperationType"
                                                    value="#{userAct.userAction}">
                                                    <f:selectItem id="newUser" itemLabel="New User"
                                                        itemValue="UMNewUser" />
                                                    <f:selectItem id="modifyUser" itemLabel="Modify User"
                                                        itemValue="UMModifyUser" />
                                                    <f:selectItem id="deleteUser" itemLabel="Delete User"
                                                        itemValue="UMDeleteUser" />
                                                    <f:selectItem id="modifyPassword"
                                                        itemLabel="Change / Reset Password"
                                                        itemValue="UMModifyPassword" />
                                                    <p:ajax update="ContentPanel"
                                                        listener="#{userAct.returnSelectedValue}" />
                                                </p:selectOneRadio>
                                            </p:fieldset>
                                        </p:column>
                                    </p:row>
                                    <p:row>
                                        <p:column>
                                            <p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true" life="20000"
                                                autoUpdate="true" />
                                            <p:outputPanel id="ContentPanel" layout="block">
                                                <ui:include src="#{userAct.userAction}.xhtml" />
                                            </p:outputPanel>
                                        </p:column>
                                    </p:row>

                                </p:panelGrid>
                            </p:column>
                            <p:column>
                                <p:outputPanel id="helpPanel">
                                    <p:inputTextarea id="helpWindow" rows="18" cols="80"
                                        value="Move your mouse over various fields for instant help" />
                                </p:outputPanel>
                            </p:column>
                        </p:row>
                    </p:panelGrid>
                </p:tab>
                <p:tab id="userGroupManagementTab" title="User Group Mgmt">
                </p:tab>
            </p:tabView>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</f:view>
</html>
```

header.xhtml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui:composition
        xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
        xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
        xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
        xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">        
                                <p:panelGrid id="pnlgLocaleChange" border="0">
                                <p:row>
                                        <p:column rowspan="2">
                                                <p:graphicImage value="images/TelenorLogoWhite.png" />
                                        </p:column>
                                        <p:column colspan="3" style="width:16%">
                                                <h:outputText id="ApplicationBanner" class="bannerLabel"
                                                        value="#{msgs.title}" />
                                                <h:outputText id="ApplicationVersion" value="#{msgs.Version} #{UsersBean.releaseLabel}" class="ApplicationVersion"/>
                                        </p:column>
                                </p:row>
                                <p:row>
                                        <p:column styleClass="LoginBannerLocale" style="padding-right: 0px !important;">
                                                <h:outputText id="languageLabel" value="#{msgs.locale}" />
                                        </p:column>
                                        <p:column style="width:5%;">
                                                <p:selectOneMenu value="#{language.locale}" styleClass="localeSelectClass">
                                                        <f:selectItems value="#{language.countries}" />
                                                        <p:ajax update="@form" />
                                                </p:selectOneMenu>
                                        </p:column>
                                </p:row>
                                <p:row rendered="#{not empty request.remoteUser}">
                                        <!-- <p:column styleClass="HeaderWelcomeMsg" >
                                                <h:outputText value="#{msgs.Welcome}, #{authenticatedBackingBean.userFullName}" style="float:middle !important; "/>
                                        </p:column> -->
                                        <p:column styleClass="LoginBannerLocale" colspan="2">
                                                <h:outputText id="loggedInUser" value="#{msgs.loginUserMessage} #{request.remoteUser } (#{authenticatedBackingBean.roleDescription})| " />  
                                                <h:commandLink value=" #{msgs.Logout}" onclick="document.getElementById('headerForm').action='ibm_security_logout?logoutExitPage=/Login.xhtml';" />
                                        </p:column>
                                </p:row>

                        </p:panelGrid>
</ui:composition>
```

AppUserManagement.xhtml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui:composition xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
        xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
        xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
        xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

                <p:fieldset id="fieldAppUserMgmt">
                        <p:panelGrid id="filterUsers" style="width:100%;">
                                <p:row>
                                        <p:column style="left: 40%;">
                                                <h:outputText id="applicationNameLabel" value="#{msgs.AppUserMgmt_AppName_Label}" />                                    
                                                <p:selectOneMenu value="#{AppUserManagementBean.applicationName}" styleClass="localeSelectClass" id="applicationName">
                                                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue="-1" />
                                                        <f:selectItems value="#{AppUserManagementBean.systemDetails}" />
                                                        <p:ajax update="groupName,userList" listener="#{AppUserManagementBean.loadGroupDetails}" />
                                                </p:selectOneMenu>
                                        </p:column>
                                </p:row>
                                <p:row>
                                        <p:column style="left: 40%;">
                                                <h:outputText id="groupNameLabel" value="#{msgs.AppUserMgmt_AppGroup_Label}" />                                    
                                                <p:selectOneMenu value="#{AppUserManagementBean.groupName}" styleClass="localeSelectClass" id="groupName">
                                                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue="-1" />
                                                        <f:selectItems value="#{AppUserManagementBean.groupDetails}" />
                                                        <p:ajax update="userList" listener="#{AppUserManagementBean.loadUserDetails}" />                                                                                                                
                                                </p:selectOneMenu>
                                        </p:column>
                                </p:row>
                                <p:row>
                                    <p:column>
                                        <p:dataTable id="userList" var="user" value="#{AppUserManagementBean.lstUsrDetails}" 
                                            paginatorAlwaysVisible="false" paginator="true" rows="10" 
                                            paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}   #{msgs.AppUserMgmt_AppUsers_List_PageSizeLabel} {RowsPerPageDropdown}" 
                                            rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15" rowIndexVar="rowNum" filteredValue="#{AppUserManagementBean.lstFilteredUsrDetails}"
                                            widgetVar="usersFilter" rowKey="#{user.userId}" selectionMode="single" selection="#{AppUserManagementBean.selectedUser}">  

                                                <f:facet name="header">                                                           
                                                        <h:outputText id="appUsrMgmtUserListHeader" style="float:left" value="#{AppUserManagementBean.applicationName} #{msgs.AppUserMgmt_AppUsers_List_Title}"/>
                                                        <p:inputText id="globalFilter" onkeyup="usersFilter.filter()"  style="float:right"/>
                                                        <p:watermark forElement="tabView:userList:globalFilter" value="#{msgs.AppUserMgmt_AppUsers_List_Find}"/>
                                                </f:facet>

                                                <p:column id="colRowNo" headerText="#{msgs.AppUserMgmt_AppUsers_List_RowNo}">  
                                                    <h:outputText value="#{rowNum+1}" />  
                                                </p:column>

                                                <p:column id="colUserID" headerText="#{msgs.AppUserMgmt_AppUsers_List_UserID}" filterBy="#{user.userId}" filterMatchMode="contains"  style="text-align:bottom" filterStyle="display:none;visibility:hidden">  
                                                    <h:outputText value="#{user.userId}" />    
                                                </p:column>  

                                                <p:column id="colName" headerText="#{msgs.AppUserMgmt_AppUsers_List_FullName}" filterBy="#{user.firstName} #{user.lastName}" filterMatchMode="contains" style="text-align:bottom" filterStyle="display:none;visibility:hidden">  
                                                    <h:outputText value="#{user.firstName} #{user.lastName}" />  
                                                </p:column>                                             
                                                <p:column id="colRole" headerText="#{msgs.AppUserMgmt_AppUsers_List_Group}" filterBy="#{user.role}" filterMatchMode="contains" style="text-align:bottom" filterStyle="display:none;visibility:hidden">  
                                                    <h:outputText value="#{user.role}" />  
                                                </p:column>  

                                                <p:column id="colEmail" headerText="#{msgs.AppUserMgmt_AppUsers_List_Email}" filterBy="#{user.email}" filterMatchMode="contains" style="text-align:bottom" filterStyle="display:none;visibility:hidden">  
                                                    <h:outputText value="#{user.email}" />  
                                                </p:column>  

                                                <p:column id="colExpiryDate" headerText="#{msgs.AppUserMgmt_AppUsers_List_ExpiresOn}"  filterBy="#{user.expiryDate}" filterMatchMode="contains" style="text-align:bottom" filterStyle="display:none;visibility:hidden">  
                                                    <h:outputText value="#{user.expiryDate}" />  
                                                </p:column>      
                                                <f:facet name="footer">  
                                                    <p:commandButton id="addUserButton" value="#{msgs.AppUserMgmt_AppUsers_NewUser_ButtonLabel}" icon="ui-icon-circle-plus" update=":headerForm:panelGridNewUserDialog" oncomplete="addNewUserDialog.show()"/>
                                                </f:facet>                                                                                                                                  
                                        </p:dataTable>                                      
                                    </p:column>
                                </p:row>
                        </p:panelGrid>
                </p:fieldset>  
                <p:dialog id="addNewUserDialog" header="#{msgs.AppUserMgmt_AppUsers_NewUser_Dialog_Header} #{AppUserManagementBean.groupName},#{AppUserManagementBean.applicationName}" widgetVar="addUserDialog" resizable="false"  
                              width="400" showEffect="clip" hideEffect="fold">
                            <p:panelGrid id="panelGridNewUserDialog" styleClass="insertPage">
                                <p:row>
                                <p:column>
                                        <h:outputText id="userIDDialog" value="#{msgs.userId}" />
                                </p:column>
                                </p:row>                            
                            </p:panelGrid>
                </p:dialog> 
</ui:composition>
```

Am I missing some thing here? I have tried to find the related question in stack but could not find any. I am happy to be redirected to right question or link if any.

I would appreciate anyone's help.

```
                                            <tfoot>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td class="ui-datatable-footer ui-widget-header"
                                                        colspan="6">
                                                        <button id="tabView:userList:addUserButton" name="tabView:userList:addUserButton"
                                                            class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-icon-left">
```

Rest of the code is not sent to browser. Lot of HTML code is not rendereed. May be some HTTP header are missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set `dynamic="true"` which means that tabs are lazy loaded. That's why is your html code incomplete. Remove this attribute and see what's happening.

Also you wrote addNewUserDialog.show(), but your widget var name is addUserDialog, so try with addUserDialog.show().

Comment: Isn't your `tabView` inside some form? Can you give little bit more of **dashboard.xhtml**?

Comment: dashboard.xhtml is has tabView. Pls see my post below for more details about dashboard.xhtml

Comment: Try to update `:headerForm:tabView:panelGridNewUserDialog` instead.

Comment: the problem is that HTML response that is sent to browser is not completely sent to browser by server.`code`
             <tfoot>
              <tr>
               <td class="ui-datatable-footer ui-widget-header"
                colspan="6">
                <button id="tabView:userList:addUserButton" name="tabView:userList:addUserButton"
                 class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-icon-left">`code`  the html code is not rendered till </html> tag. lot of code is missing. May be some HTTP headers that I need to set?

Comment: @SatyaYeditha, might be a transport layer issue. is all this happening on localhost?

Comment: application is not running locally. I have put dialog out side of **h:form** and added **h:form** with in the **<p:dialog></p:dialog>**. Now HTML is rendering completely, but when click the button dialog is not popping up.....

Comment: any one has idea why dialog box is not popping up on click of button?

Comment: Because you wrote `addNewUserDialog.show()`, but your widget var name is `addUserDialog`, so try with `addUserDialog.show()`.

Comment: Thats my mistake, corrected. working now. Partial rendering occurs if any component that is referred from update attribute is not in the page

Comment: OK, I added this also to answer.

Answer (score 0):

You must try update "`:headerForm:tabView:panelGridNewUserDialog`"

with `formId="headerForm"` at the beginning and add `":"`